# «Раньше то никак?» или «Раньше-то никак?»

Tags: орфография, грамматика, раздельно-дефис

Нужен ли дефис в этом случае: "Раньше-то никак?"

Именно в этом конкретном случае.

Если Вы хотите сослаться на правила, хорошо, ссылайтесь, но в конце напишите правильный вариант.

А не как обычно, описали правила, которые в свободном доступе, а объяснения не поступило, и вопрос остался открытым. Потому как мне необходим конкретный ответ, на конкретный вопрос. Нужен ли дефис в этом, конкретном, случае?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно с дефисом:

***Раньше-то никак?***

> **-ТО,** *частица.* **1.** Употр. для подчёркивания и выделения в предложении слова, к которому относится. *Я-то понимаю. Ночь-то какая тёплая! Слушать-то слушал, да ничего не понял. Где-то он сейчас? **Что дальше-то делать будешь?***

Источник: [**Большой толковый словарь**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D0%BE&all=x) (Грамота.ру).

> **§ 86.** Пишутся через дефис:
> <...>
> 3. Слова с частицей ***кое-, кой-, -ка, -либо, -нибудь, -то, -тка, -с, -де,*** например: *кое-что, кое-кто, кое-какой, кой-куда, кто-нибудь, кто-либо, кто-то, давай-ка, как-нибудь, как-либо, как-то, ну-тка, да-с.*

Источник: [**Предлоги, союзы, частицы, междометия**](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/137-def-19-23) (Грамота.ру).

Answer (score 1):

Дефис нужен:

***Раньше-то никак?***

Частица ***-ТО*** пишется через дефис. Её следует отличать от указательного местоимения ТО (*то дерево*).